# Use query in a data macro ms access web app

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I am using Access 2013 Web apps to build an application. I have one table containing

```
> 1. id   (primary key)
> 
>2. Code (short text)
>
>3. Name (short text)
>
> 4. Type (Short Text)
```

This is how the data looks inside this table

[Table 1]

```
id    Code   Name   Type
1     1aa     Jim    R
2     1aa     Jak    R
3     1aa     Mak    I
4     1ba     Jim    I
5     1ba     Jak    R
6     1ba     Mak    R
7     1ab     Jim    R
8     1ab     Jak    I
9     1ab     Mak    I
```

What I need to do is find unique values from [Code] and display it in a autocomplete box, and when the user picks one, the next autocomplete box only has the corresponding [Name]. After the user has picked the [Name], the next text box displays the [Type].

This is what I have done so far:

I have a query [qryUnique] that looks at [Table 1] and has one field selected [Name] and total is a Group by, so that displays all unique values for [Name]. Now I write a data macro and do a [look up a record] in the [qryUnique] and a [SetReturnVar] but when I add this data macro to [OnClick] macro it throws an error.

I have looked everywhere for an answer, however, this is proving quite difficult with the limited Web App functions Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, for `qryUnique`, if there are 2 identical names it will only return 1 value. I wouldn't necessarily say it returns all 'unique' `[Name]` values. And what is the error from the macro?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The unique query in essence runs on the `[code]` and it should give me unique code values i.e. _1aa_, _1ba_, _1ab_ and then the `[name]` autocomplete should only show the corresponding fields. 

When I put my data macro in the onClick macro and save and run the app, it still shows me all the fields and not only the unique ones. So, I wanted to know if I doing the right thing and/or what is the way to go forward. Please let me know if this is not clear. Thank you

Comment: A little bit more detail, `qryUnique` has the `[code]` field and in the `Total` I use `[Group By]` to select the unique values. Then I try two things, one is to directly change the row source of the `[code]` in the form to `qryUnique` but then I get an error that `Bound Field` cannot be `[id]`. The other way is to put in a data macro; I `look up a record` in `qryUnique` `SetRetunVar` and put this data macro in an OnClick Macro. None of the two seem to work. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. @Invent-Animate